# XML cleanup in PHP (SOAP > XML/JSON)

Tags: php, xml, json, soap

I'm using (and hating) a webservice which only returns data in a SOAP XML format for a mail carrier service (why won't the return JSONP? please!)

The thing is I will be "consuming" the data in jQuery so I'm trying to convert the information into JSON and using PHP as a proxy since XML can't be loaded cross-domain and I don't want to rely on YQL

There are many scripts to convert XML to JSON but the xml returned from the webservice has to be cleaned a lot before it can be run inside this script or they'll throw a bunch of errors.

The first part of the xml returned is a schema or Dataset, so there is no data there and I need the schema out of the JSON so I remove it in php with `strstr(first data ocurrence)`

But then I have this...

```
    <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <Numero>301</Numero>
      <Torre xml:space="preserve"></Torre>
      <Piso xml:space="preserve"></Piso>
      <Depto xml:space="preserve"></Depto>
      <Localidad>SAN ISIDRO</Localidad>
      <eMail/>
      <Provincia>Buenos Aires</Provincia>
    </Table>
    <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
      <Numero>34</Numero>
      <Torre xml:space="preserve"></Torre>
      <Piso xml:space="preserve"></Piso>
      <Depto xml:space="preserve"></Depto>
      <Localidad>DON TORCUATO</Localidad>
      <eMail/>
      <Provincia>Buenos Aires</Provincia>
  </Table>
```

I need to remove all tag attributes like `diffgr:id="Table2"` so I can cleanly convert this to JSON. I did some replacing like `str_replace(xml:space="preserve", "")` but I still have attributes with variable content like `msdata:rowOrder="0"`

I think that the best way to do this last thing with `preg_replace` but I have 2 problems with this:

- I'm not very good with regular expressions and the regex generators I found all leave me with "leaving" a string and not removing
- Even if I try and try until I get the correct regex for "id" and "row" I get the feeling that doing a several rounds of replaces and then 2 regexs is very un-efficient. I only pasted 2 items but the response may have hundreds and the CURL to the webservice is already taking a lot of time and the proxy will take lots of hits, I need to optimize this as much as possible.

Is there a better way to convert  `<Table diffgr:id="Table**N**" msdata:rowOrder="**N**">` to `<Table>` or even better, to remove everything after ''... or to even much better to convert the raw SOAP XML to JSON in only one magical step :P ?

Comment: Start here http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php :-)

Comment: didn't think about that. will look into it. thanks Jack

Comment: Be forewarned - that library is a PITA. I used it to do something similar a few years back and it took almost half the day to figure it all out. If I had the code still I would have written an answer for you - but it is long lost.

Comment: @Jack: That library is the standard DOMDocument interface in PHP. This is *the standard*. So even if you learn it only in PHP, you can use it in Java, inside the Browser and so on and so forth - so I won't judge that fast only because of half a day.

Comment: `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` are your friends here. You will likely be able to setup some `DOMXPath` object with the needed namespaces registered and then just run a few queries to remove stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP xpath query on XML with default namespace binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475394/php-xpath-query-on-xml-with-default-namespace-binding)

Comment: @hakre - Thanks. By PITA, I meant that the documentation on php.net wasn't very great IIRC and I spent a lot of time flipping through various methods hoping that the examples would have what I was looking for. The descriptions are very thin on php.net - so if you know of a better resource for documentation on DOMElement - it would probably benefit Juan.

Comment: We have good postings here on SO as well. And also the Docs on PHP.net are constantly improving. However you might find more examples here on this website.